# Trying to 'Delete Cascade' from an already created table with 'alter'

Tags: postgresql

so I'm a little lost here because most of the examples I can find seem to use a slightly different SQL syntax. Right now I have an 'account' table, a 'projects' table, and a 'tasks' table.

Projects have a reference to account, and Tasks have a reference to both Account and Projects.

For starters, when a Project is deleted I'd like all associated Tasks to be deleted. I think you can do this with Delete Cascade in an Alter statement, but I'm having trouble.

I've found this example that uses a transaction, but my syntax for creating a reference is slightly different and it is confusing me. https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/07139c566b-add-on-delete-cascade-to-foreign-key-constraint

here are my tables

```
CREATE TABLE account (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    account_username TEXT NOT NULL,
    email TEXT NOT NULL,
    password TEXT NOT NULL,
    date_published TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT now() NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE project (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    account INTEGER REFERENCES account(id) NOT NULL,
    project TEXT NOT NULL,
    date_published TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT now() NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE task (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    account INTEGER REFERENCES account(id) NOT NULL,
    project INTEGER REFERENCES project(id) NOT NULL,
    task TEXT NOT NULL,
    cycle INTEGER NOT NULL,
    date_published TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT now() NOT NULL
);
```

Can anyone help me out with what the transaction (or maybe just the alter statement) looks like in my case.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try, and what problem did you encounter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to drop the account column from `task`. When you need to `task` with account information just get it through `project`. This also makes maintenance must easier. With account in both `task` and `project` how do you ensure both accounts are the same.  
Since Postgres does not have `alter constraint...` you need to drop and recreate the FK in `project` and `task`. Following are the alter statements you need.

```
alter table task drop column account; 
alter table task drop constraint task_project_fkey;        -- verify constraint name 
alter table task add constraint  task_project_fkey
                     foreign key (project) 
                     references project(id)  
                     on delete cascade; 
alter table project drop constraint project_account_fkey;    -- verify constraint name 
alter table project add constraint  project_account_fkey
                        foreign key (account) 
                        references account(id)  
                        on delete cascade;
```

As you took the lazy way of defining FK, you will have to verify the constraint names.  
**NOTE:** It is poor practice to name a column the same a the table it is in. So perhaps project.name (or project.description) instead of project.project. Especially since any FK referring to project table do not refer to the
project column in that table. Of course the same applies `task` and any other table in your system.